# Trying to Run the node script for revenue distribution for Waves nodes and leasers. But getting the socket hang up error,In HTTP call of node script

Tags: node.js, ajax, blockchain, bitcoin, wavesplatform

I Used this GitHub repository as a reference. https://github.com/plukkie/WavesLPoSDistributer

In that, config.json file is setup with all the details related to waves node. But' when i'm trying to run the script for collector sessions. I'm facing the socket hangup error. which is due to http request in node address.

Below is the code Which is responsible for generating error:

```
     var getAllAlias = function() {

     var AliasArr = [];
            var Aliases = JSON.parse(request('GET', config.node + '/alias/by-address/' + config.address, {
                'headers': {
                    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
                }
            }).getBody('utf8'));

        Aliases.forEach(function(alias)
        {
                         AliasArr.push(alias);
                         console.log(alias);
        });
    return AliasArr;
    }
```

Any help on this would be great, Thankyou

Comment: Please copy paste error messages, don't use screenshot.
socket hangup error usually means some protocol mismatch (https instead of http) or the request that server does not understand.

Comment: I tried with https instead of http but still getting same error message @YuriGinsburg

Comment: So, server closes connection for some other reason. Server log files may really help, also useful is to run client in debug mode. 
One of possible reasons of such error is versions mismatch.

Comment: ThankYou @YuriGinsburg for your response, Actually i'm trying to request on url from vnc and the Ip address of vnc and the the requested url ip is on same server also the server we used is VPS S SSD. Do you think any of above causing issue.